# How to get RIP after segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, gdb

I compiled a C program on linux, while running I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Istead I want something like:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x41414141 in ?? ()
```

I tried using gdb but is the same.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it is you're asking, but if you are running in GDB, you can get a backtrace after it segfaults.

Comment: I want to know which value got loaded into the istruction pointer

Comment: in gdb use info registers(print values of all registers) at crash point

Comment: @SimoneDeVita *I want to know which value got loaded into the istruction pointer* That's what the core file is for.

Comment: How can I access the core file?

Comment: Run `gdb` with the `core` file and execute `info registers`.

Comment: `cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` will show you where your system puts the files and what they're called. `man 5 core` for more details.

Comment: Or, just run the program inside gdb in the first place, and it will show you the exact state when the SEGV occurs.

Comment: Ok thanks. But can anyone explain me why are there two different messages (the ones in my question)?

Comment: The first message is the message you get when you run a program that segfaults directly from the shell.  The second message is the message you get when you run a program that segfaults from within gdb.  In the second message, 0x41414141 is the value that was loaded into the instruction pointer.  I don't understand what you mean by "I tried using gdb but is the same" -- please post the _complete and unedited_ transcript of your gdb session and then explain how that's not what you wanted to see.

Comment: Sorry, I was doing something wrong... now I can see the instruction pointer in gdb. Thank you all.